# Botão voltar problema/Duvida

Tags: php

Estou com um problema num botão voltar porque tenho uma pagina trabalhadores que pode ser aberta em vários sítios por ser o ID1

Exemplo:
Query positivos: Mostra-me a página trabalhadores

Query negativos: Mostra-me a página trabalhadores

Como consigo colocar um botão voltar para a página anterior sendo eles paginas diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está difícil de entender o que você quis dizer, mas que quer voltar para a página anterior antes de acessar a página trabalhadores independentemente de qual for.

Se for essa a sua necessidade, o código abaixo resolverá o seu problema.

jQuery:

```
$('.voltar').click(function() {
    history.back()
});
```